# How to open link in new window sharepoint 2013 foundation

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

What would be the ideal way to open a link in new window in a link list?
Any resources would be appreciated

Comment: Regardless of the language? Like javascript etc?

Comment: Please provide more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done out of the box. Depending on your situation, you would need a customized template for a content query web part or some custom javascript that binds to anchor tags and  adds a target="_blank" element to them. This could be tricky as you don't want all anchor tags to open new tabs.

More specifics on your use case would help us pinpoint a solution for you.

Comment: created a custom webpart using sharepoint designer with target=_blank